# Gradle mlReloadModules not loading REST extensions

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version - 9.0-6.2
DHF Version : 2.0.6 (id 'com.marklogic.ml-data-hub' version '2.0.6')

Trying to deploy changes through 'gradle mlReloadModules' command but noticed that the REST extension billing.sjs is not being deployed. This file (billing.sjs) is saved at \data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services and I executed 'gradle mlReloadmodules' command several times from \data-hub\EODH directory

I went to data-hub-MODULES db and browsed /marklogic.rest.resource/billing/assets/resource.sjs to see that the old code is still present there.

I also did 'rm .tmp/user-modules-deploy-timestamps.properties' before reloading modules.

Below is a selected section of output from 'gradle mlReloadmodules -d' command

> 23:17:34.455 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.EntityDefModulesFinder]
>   Finding modules in baseDir: G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing
>   23:17:34.455 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.EntityDefModulesFinder]
>   Finding modules in baseDir, which was modified to be:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/ 23:17:34.455 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.EntityDefModulesFinder]
>   Finding Entity Def at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/*.entity.json
>   23:17:34.455 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing] 23:17:34.456 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Searching directory [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing] for
>   files matching pattern
>   [G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/*.entity.json] 23:17:34.456
>   [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/*.entity.json] to
>   resources [] 23:17:34.457 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   Loading modules from base directory:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST 23:17:34.470
>   [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.PropertiesModuleManager]
>   Loading properties from:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH.tmp\user-modules-deploy-timestamps.properties
>   23:17:34.470 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding modules in baseDir:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST 23:17:34.470
>   [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding modules in baseDir, which was modified to be:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/
>   23:17:34.470 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding namespaces at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/namespaces/*.*
>   23:17:34.471 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\namespaces]
>   23:17:34.471 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Skipping
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\namespaces]
>   because it does not exist 23:17:34.471 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/namespaces/*.*]
>   to resources [] 23:17:34.471 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding options modules at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/options/*.*
>   23:17:34.471 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\options]
>   23:17:34.471 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Searching directory
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\options] for
>   files matching pattern
>   [G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/options/*.*]
>   23:17:34.472 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/options/*.*]
>   to resources [file
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\options\BillingInfoList.json]]
>   23:17:34.472 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding REST properties file at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/rest-properties.json 23:17:34.472 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding service modules at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/*.xq*
>   23:17:34.472 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services]
>   23:17:34.472 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Searching directory
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services]
>   for files matching pattern
>   [G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/*.xq*]
>   23:17:34.473 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/*.xq*]
>   to resources [] 23:17:34.473 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding service modules at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/*.sjs
>   23:17:34.473 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services]
>   23:17:34.473 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Searching directory
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services]
>   for files matching pattern
>   [G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/*.sjs]
>   23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/*.sjs]
>   to resources [file
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services\billing.sjs],
>   file
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services\billing360.sjs],
>   file
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services\billingReg.sjs]]
>   23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding transform modules at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/transforms/*.xq*
>   23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\transforms]
>   23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Skipping
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\transforms]
>   because it does not exist 23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/transforms/*.xq*]
>   to resources [] 23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding transform modules at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/transforms/*.xsl*
>   23:17:34.474 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\transforms]
>   23:17:34.475 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Skipping
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\transforms]
>   because it does not exist 23:17:34.475 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/transforms/*.xsl*]
>   to resources [] 23:17:34.475 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.modules.AllButAssetsModulesFinder]
>   Finding transform modules at path:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/transforms/*.sjs
>   23:17:34.475 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Looking for matching resources in directory tree
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\transforms]
>   23:17:34.475 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Skipping
>   [G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\transforms]
>   because it does not exist 23:17:34.475 [DEBUG]
>   [org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver]
>   Resolved location pattern
>   [file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/transforms/*.sjs]
>   to resources [] 23:17:34.475 [INFO]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   Loading BillingInfoList query options from file BillingInfoList.json
>   23:17:34.489 [DEBUG] [com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices]
>   Putting /config/query/BillingInfoList 23:17:34.529 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultExtensionMetadataProvider]
>   Unable to build metadata from resource file:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/billing.sjs;
>   cause:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services\metadata\billing.xml
>   (The system cannot find the file specified) 23:17:34.530 [INFO]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   Loading billing resource extension from file billing.sjs 23:17:34.540
>   [INFO] [com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceExtensionsImpl] Writing
>   resource services source for billing 23:17:34.540 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices] Putting
>   config/resources/billing 23:17:34.552 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultExtensionMetadataProvider]
>   Unable to build metadata from resource file:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/billing360.sjs;
>   cause:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services\metadata\billing360.xml
>   (The system cannot find the file specified) 23:17:34.553 [INFO]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   Loading billing360 resource extension from file billing360.sjs
>   23:17:34.560 [INFO] [com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceExtensionsImpl]
>   Writing resource services source for billing360 23:17:34.560 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices] Putting
>   config/resources/billing360 23:17:34.576 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultExtensionMetadataProvider]
>   Unable to build metadata from resource file:
>   file:/G:/data-hub/EODH/plugins/entities/billing/harmonize/REST/services/billingReg.sjs;
>   cause:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services\metadata\billingReg.xml
>   (The system cannot find the file specified) 23:17:34.577 [INFO]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   Loading billingReg resource extension from file billingReg.sjs
>   23:17:34.583 [INFO] [com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceExtensionsImpl]
>   Writing resource services source for billingReg 23:17:34.583 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices] Putting
>   config/resources/billingReg 23:17:34.609 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   shutdownTaskExecutorAfterLoadingModules is set to false, so not
>   shutting down taskExecutor 23:17:34.609 [DEBUG]
>   [com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader]
>   Finished loading modules from base directory:
>   G:\data-hub\EODH\plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST

Comment: I think DHF v2 is looking at a different place for rest extensions. Did you try putting it under src/main/ml-modules/services/?

Comment: Thanks a lot. We have been deploying the same way all the time. We have not upgraded DHF in months. It worked just until yesterday. However I will try placing REST extension in the suggested folder.

Comment: It is not working from src/main/ml-modules/services/ either. Also, we are able to push the code successfully from a different machine (by keeping the code at plugins\entities\billing\harmonize\REST\services. Looks like my gradle cache is messed up and not deploying the code (even after 'rm .tmp/user-modules-deploy-timestamps.properties'). Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle task names are case insensitive. Property names are case sensitive. The case sensitivity of file paths - which may be the issue in that ticket - is determined by the OS.

One thing would be to verify that none of the [directories in your deployment path are set to case sensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17093).  Linux Tools run by Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux - Bash shell) will create folders that are case sensitive.  This default behavior can be changed by editing the [wsl.conf](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/)

You can check for Case Sensitivity by using the following command:

```
fsutil.exe file queryCaseSensitiveInfo C:\folder
```

Case sensitivity is set per directory, and does not affect sub-directories, so each directory in the file path may need to be checked.

It's also possible you may be encountering a known bug in the 4.0.x code [DHF does not deploy REST extensions](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/issues/1574).  It has since been fixed in 4.1.0 and later.

If this is the issue you are facing, would suggest moving to the latest version of [Data Hub Framework](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/releases/), as there were a lot of bug fixes and enhancements to the deployment process.

If that is not an option at this time, a workaround is detailed in the issue comments:

https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/issues/1574#issuecomment-441785549

Comment: Thanks Michael. We are using version 2.0.3. I noticed that the lower case 'mlreloadmodules' is not working but the mixed case 'mlReloadModules' is working fine. Our MarkLogic is deployed on windows (community edition) and I am running from powershell, so we did not see case sensitivity issues earlier, so this is a surprise behavior for us. I will keep an eye on the deploys and update if I find anything new.

Answer (score 0):

We are using version 2.0.3. I noticed that the lower case 'mlreloadmodules' is not working but the mixed case 'mlReloadModules' is working fine. Our MarkLogic is deployed on windows (community edition) and I am running from powershell, so we did not see case sensitivity issues earlier, so this is a surprise behavior for us. I will keep an eye on the deploys and update if I find anything new.

Thanks everyone, for your responses.